# Android Adapter and ContextMenu

Tags: android, contextmenu

I'm a newbie in android and I don't really understand the use of an adapter? I've been trying to make ContextMenu, that will pop up to at click on a item from the list: My Activity is like this without what I tried for the ContextMenu because it's useful:

```
public class Proj2Activity extends Activity {
public static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
private TweetListAdapter1 twa;
private ListView myListView;
ArrayList<TweetModel> tweets;
public static double distance(float lat_a, float lng_a, float lat_b, float lng_b) {
    float pk = (float) (180/3.14169);

    float a1 = lat_a / pk;
    float a2 = lng_a / pk;
    float b1 = lat_b / pk;
    float b2 = lng_b / pk;

    float t1 = FloatMath.cos(a1)*FloatMath.cos(a2)*FloatMath.cos(b1)*FloatMath.cos(b2);
    float t2 = FloatMath.cos(a1)*FloatMath.sin(a2)*FloatMath.cos(b1)*FloatMath.sin(b2);
    float t3 = FloatMath.sin(a1)*FloatMath.sin(b1);
    double tt = Math.acos(t1 + t2 + t3);

    return 6366000*tt;
}


public static Location getLocation(Context ctx) {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);

    /*
     * Loop over the array backwards, and if you get an accurate location,
     * then break out the loop
     */
    Location l = null;

    for (int i = providers.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
        if (l != null)
            break;
    }
    return l;
}




/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LoadTweetsTask ltt = new LoadTweetsTask("androiddev");
    ltt.execute();


    final TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nume);
    final Button btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btnGo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name1 = text1.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("My_Pref", 0);
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
              editor.putBoolean(name1, true);
              editor.commit();
             LoadTweetsTask ltt = new LoadTweetsTask(name1);
             ltt.execute();
        }
    });


}




private class LoadTweetsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public String name;


    public LoadTweetsTask(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        tweets = new ArrayList<TweetModel>();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Proj2Activity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Tweets");
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        TweetListAdapter1 adapter = new TweetListAdapter1(getApplicationContext(), tweets);
        ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.listTweets)).setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {



        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        String requestUrl = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json" + "?screen_name=" + name + "&count=200";
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(requestUrl);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

        try {
            String jsonResponse = client.execute(request, responseHandler);

            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
            //used to display 20 valid tweets from 200 tweets which have the location specified
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                if(count <= 20){
                    JSONObject jsonTweet = json.getJSONObject(i);

                    try{

                        JSONObject obj = jsonTweet.getJSONObject("geo");

                        if(obj!=null){
                            Location myLocation = getLocation(getBaseContext());
                            double distance;
                            JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("coordinates");
                            float tweetc1 = (float) arr.getDouble(0);
                            float tweetc2 = (float) arr.getDouble(1);
                            Log.d("COORDTweet",Float.toString(tweetc1)+  "  " +Float.toString(tweetc2) );
                            float my1 = (float) 44.438254;
                            float my2 = (float) 26.051009;
                            Log.d("COORDMY",Float.toString(my1)+  "  " +Float.toString(my2) );
                            distance = distance(tweetc1, tweetc2, my1, my2);
                            Log.d("Distance",Double.toString(distance));
                            tweets.add(new TweetModel(jsonTweet.getJSONObject("user").getString("name"), jsonTweet.getString("created_at"), jsonTweet.getString("text"),(int)distance/1000));

                            count++;
                        }

                        Log.d("TRY", "OK");

                    }catch(JSONException e){
                        Log.d("EXCP","NULL");
                    }

                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        catch(ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        catch (IOException e ) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        catch (JSONException e ) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;

    }

}
}
```

the adapter class :

```
public class TweetListAdapter1 extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<TweetModel> items;

public TweetListAdapter1(Context context, ArrayList<TweetModel> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_tweet, parent, false);

    TextView txtMessage = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
    TweetModel m = items.get(position);
    txtMessage.setText("Name: " + m.getName()  +"\n"+ "Distance :"+ m.getDistance() +  " Km\n" + "Tweet: " +  m.getTweet() + "\n" + "Date: " + m.getDate() + "\n");

    TextView txtMessage1 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage1);
    txtMessage1.setText("Ala bala ");
    return rowView;
}

}
```

What I want to do is to open a Context Menu with two actions: Action1 and Action2 ...

Answer (score 1):

> I've been trying to make ContextMenu, that will pop up to at click on
>   a item from the list

So you need to implement it in your `Activity` class.

First you need to override `onCreateContextMenu` and then also override `onContextItemSelected` method

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu cMenu, View parent, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo info) {
        new MenuInflater(YourActivity.this).inflate(R.menu.conmenu, cMenu);
    }

@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.option1:
                //do some work
                        break;
                        case R.id.option2:
                               // do some work
                        break;
            }
        ... 
    }
```

You need to read some tutorial so [`Android: Context menu example`](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/04/android-context-menu-example-on-long-press-gridview/) and [`Context Menu | Android Developer Tutorial`](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.cz/2011/05/context-menu-android-developer-tutorial.html)

Comment: I don't understand your answer, your post is related with activity not with adapter, please read again post!